# Subcategories in layered navigation filter

Tags: magento, filter, magento-1.7, categories, layered-navigation

I have a category with simple two-level structure like this:

```
Category #1
- Subcategory
- Subcategory
- ...
Category #2
- Subcategory
- Subcategory
- ...
```

Currently to filter by subcategories - you have to select top-level category first.

How to show subcategories of all top-level categories in layered navigation filter?

Note: Subcategories should by effected by other selected attribute filter.

Comment: for this you have to get the subcategories through loop by getting current category id

Comment: @RohitGoel I already did this in template level. The downside is that currently active filters are not applied to subcategories - so there are subcategory which will result in empty page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While experimenting with Magento files I've found the answer to my question.

1. Copy

   ```
   app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php
   ```

   to

   ```
   app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php
   ```
2. Open copied file. And replace `_getItemsData` with code below:

   ```
   /**
    * Get data array for building category filter items
    *
    * @return array
    */
   protected function _getItemsData()
   {
     $key = $this->getLayer()->getStateKey().'_SUBCATEGORIES';
     $data = $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->getCacheData($key);

     if ($data === null) {
       // Get root category
       $root_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);

       // Get main categories
       $data = array();
       $main_categories = $root_category->getChildrenCategories();
       foreach ($main_categories as $main_category) {
         if (!$main_category->getIsActive()) continue; // Ommit inactive
         // Get sub categories to list
         $sub_categories = $main_category->getChildrenCategories();

         // Add count to subcategories
         $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()
           ->addCountToCategories($sub_categories);

         foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_category) {
           // Ommit inactive and zero product count sub categories
           if ($sub_category->getIsActive() || !$sub_category->getProductCount()) continue;

           // Output subcategories
           $data[] = array(
             'label' => Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($sub_category->getName()),
             'value' => $sub_category->getId(),
             'count' => $sub_category->getProductCount(),
             'parent' => $main_category->getName(), // Store parent name to group in template
           );
         }
       }

       $tags = $this->getLayer()->getStateTags();
       $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->saveCacheData($data, $key, $tags);
     }
     return $data;
   }
   ```

You might be interested in rewriting some other functions such as `getResetValue`, etc.
I had to rewrite template to group subcategories by main categories.

**Result** (sorry cant post images directly):

Before:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/skZpi.png

After:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxPhq.png

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to show all subcategories of a current category in your sidebar or wherever

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Active filters are not applied to subcategories, so some subcategory links leads to empty result page. How to apply curretly active layered navigation filters to `$_category->getChildrenCategories()`?

Comment: can you please provide the link of your site